How can I setup winit + slint + skia?
I have an idea for project. After hours of researching I figured out that I want to use winit for window management, Slint for UI and Skia for some widgets which demand high performance (canvas for drawing for example) I will sent them to Slint custom widget. Now I faced with problem that I cant find actual information how can I integrate winit with slint, the wgpu/skia etc need the concrete context for work.
How can I set everything up?
